# Show that a subspace is complete

Tags: metric-spaces

> Consider $\mathbb{R}$ with it's usual Euclidean metric. Show that the subspace $[a,b]$ is complete, with $a<b$ in $\mathbb{R}$

I know that for a subspace to be complete, every Cauchy sequence in it must converge in that subspace. How do I apply this to the question? Do I just point out that because $[a,b]$ is closed that it contains all of the limits of the sequences contained in it, and therefore complete?

Comment: $\Bbb R$ is complete, and any closed subspace of a complete metric space is complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's basically it.

For classwork it would probably be good to add just a few more intermediate steps along the lines of

> Suppose we have a sequence that's Cauchy in $[a,b]$. Since the metric on $[a,b]$ is a restriction of the metric on $\mathbb R$, the sequence is also Cauchy in $\mathbb R$, and therefore (since $\mathbb R$ is complete) it has a limit in $\mathbb R$. This limit must actually be in $[a,b]$ because ...